# How to interpret = and === in the same line?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've come across this snippet of code

```
render: function() {
    var boards = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < this.props.numBoards; ii++) {
      // We can compare to state here so we're no longer always selecting the first board.
      var isSelected = ii === this.state.selectedIndex;
      boards.push(
        <Board index={ii} selected={isSelected}  />

      );
    }
```

How is the line `isSelected = ii === this.state.selectedIndex` executed?

Here's the full code: http://jsbin.com/dagavu/4/embed?css,js,output

Comment: fix the title.........

Comment: I know it doesnt affect your question,but this is not valid javascript.  The section starting with <Board is from a template engine or something.

Comment: what should i change the title to?

Comment: @Tony54: ffs, focus a little bit... don't you see it's wrong?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath perhaps rather than that you should update it for him.

Comment: Nikhil has shown what the meaning of this line is.  Good programming practice would do the following to remove all confusion.


     `var isSelected = (ii === this.state.selectedIndex); `  

by using unrequired parenthesis it leaves no doubt to either what happens or what is intended.

Comment: @TobyAllen: You have to draw the line somewhere, and not disambiguate the obvious... otherwise you'll create tons of noise that will make the code more difficult to read.

Comment: I don't think anyone would suggest that using parenthesis to succintly indicate the order your code runs would be noise.

Comment: I just did that. If the meaning is obvious to a non-beginner, it's noise. To draw an analogy, you wouldn't consider adding comments as noise either... yet, adding stuff like `// I'm creating a variable here`, which might be usefull for a novice is considered just pure noise in production code. As I said, you have to draw the line somewhere. Looks like we're disagreeing about what is *obvious*. I wouldn't like to have a coder on my team who needs those parentheses, that's for sure...

Comment: I wouldn't like to have a coder on my team who didnt think they were required :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is executed in 2 steps

```
isSelected = ii === this.state.selectedIndex

1. ii === this.state.selectedIndex // comparator operator
2. isSelected = (result of step 1) // assignment operator
```

Comment: are you sure step 2 isnt performed first?

Comment: @TobyAllen how can step 2 be performed first if it involves the RESULT of step 1?

Comment: You're correct, list of precedence here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 4):

For clarity that line should be written as:

```
isSelected = (ii === this.state.selectedIndex);
```

This is because `==` and `===` are for comparisons, the statement `ii === this.state.selectedIndex` will return either `true` or `false` and therefore `isSelected` will be `true` or `false`. Just like how `if (ii === this.state.selectedIndex)` will only execute its code block if the comparison statement is true.